# Can I install sitecore10 without installing container with it?

Tags: sitecore-install-framework, docker, container

I don't need to use docker in my local training env. Is it possible to not install containers when installing `Sitecore 10` or is it mandatory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not required to install Sitecore using docker. You can easily install it using `Sitecore Installation Assistant (SIA)`. Installing Sitecore 10 using Sitecore Installation Assistant (SIA) is quick and easy. Below are the 10 steps to get you started.

1. Install SQL Server 2017 or 2019 and SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS).
2. [Download](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Platform/100/Sitecore_Experience_Platform_100.aspx) Sitecore 10 Graphical setup package for XP Single.
3. Extract the content of the zip and initiate the setup.
4. On the Welcome screen, click Start to begin the setup.
5. Install the pre-requisites. This should install SIF and Windows Server prerequisites including IIS and other modules.
6. Once prerequisites are installed successfully, you may have to restart the machine. Install Solr search service. Sitecore 10 needs SOLR 8.4
7. After SOLR is installed enter the Sitecore settings i.e. admin password and provide a license file.
8. Provide the SQL server settings i.e. SQL server name, admin username, and password.
9. Provide the SOLR details – service URL, root path the cores should be created and SOLR service name.
10. Optionally select Sitecore modules (SXA).

That’s it, SIA takes care of everything to successfully install Sitecore 10 on a dev machine

Refer to this article to know more about the installation steps.

https://assurex.co/quick-tips/10-steps-to-install-sitecore-10-using-sia/

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, You can install Sitecore 10 without using containers. It's not mandatory to use Sitecore with containers.** One of the simplest way is to use `Graphical setup package for XP Single` with `SIA` (Sitecore Installation Assistant) for local or training environments.

[image]

**Sitecore 10 Download link:** https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Platform/100/Sitecore_Experience_Platform_100.aspx

**Check this blog for step-by-step installation:** https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/install-sitecore-10-step-by-step-using-sia/

Hope it helps!